# aggregate a matrix (or data.frame) by column name groups in R

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I have a large matrix with about 3000 columns x 3000 rows.  I'd like to aggregate (calculate the mean) grouped by column names for every row.  Each column is named similar to this method...(and in random order)

```
 Tree Tree House House Tree Car Car House
```

I would need the data result (aggregation of mean of every row) to have the following columns:

```
  Tree House Car
```

- the tricky part (at least for me) is that I do not know all the column names and they are all in random order!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with my own solution.  I first just transpose the matrix (called test_mean) so the columns become rows,then:

```
# removing numbers from rownames
rownames(test_mean)<-gsub("[0-9.]","",rownames(test_mean))


#aggregate by rownames
test_mean<-aggregate(test_mean, by=list(rownames(test_mean)), FUN=mean)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
res1 <- vapply(unique(colnames(m1)), function(x) 
      rowMeans(m1[,colnames(m1)== x,drop=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE),
                             numeric(nrow(m1)) )
```

Or

```
res2 <-  sapply(unique(colnames(m1)), function(x) 
       rowMeans(m1[,colnames(m1)== x,drop=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE) )

identical(res1,res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Another option might be to reshape into long form and then do the aggregation

```
 library(data.table)
 res3 <-dcast.data.table(setDT(melt(m1)), Var1~Var2, fun=mean)[,Var1:= NULL]
 identical(res1, as.matrix(res3))
 [1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

It seems like the first two methods are slightly faster for a 3000*3000 matrix

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:40, 3000*3000, replace=TRUE), 
   ncol=3000, dimnames=list(NULL, sample(c('Tree', 'House', 'Car'),
    3000,replace=TRUE)))

library(microbenchmark)

f1 <-function() {vapply(unique(colnames(m1)), function(x) 
     rowMeans(m1[,colnames(m1)== x,drop=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE),
                           numeric(nrow(m1)) )}
f2 <- function() {sapply(unique(colnames(m1)), function(x) 
       rowMeans(m1[,colnames(m1)== x,drop=FALSE], na.rm=TRUE) )}

f3 <- function() {dcast.data.table(setDT(melt(m1)), Var1~Var2, fun=mean)[,
            Var1:= NULL]}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative", times=10L)
#   Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
# f2() 1.026208 1.027723 1.037593 1.034516 1.028847 1.079004    10
# f3() 4.529037 4.567816 4.834498 4.855776 4.930984 5.529531    10
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(0:40, 10*40, replace=TRUE), ncol=10, 
     dimnames=list(NULL, sample(c("Tree", "House", "Car"), 10, replace=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`matrixStats:rowMeans2`](https://rdrr.io/cran/matrixStats/man/rowMeans2.html) with some coercive help from data.table, for the win!

Adding it to benchmarking from @akrun we get:

```
f4<- function() {
  ucn<-unique(colnames(m1))
  as.matrix(setnames(setDF(lapply(ucn, function(n) rowMeans2(m1,cols=colnames(m1)==n)))
                    ,ucn))
  }

> all.equal(f4(),f1())
[1] TRUE

> microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), unit="relative", times=10L)
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 f1()  1.837496  1.841282  1.823375  1.834471  1.818822  1.749826    10  b 
 f2()  1.760133  1.825352  1.817355  1.826257  1.838439  1.793824    10  b 
 f3() 15.451106 15.606912 15.847117 15.586192 16.626629 16.104648    10   c
 f4()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    10 a
```